# PHP, помогите с регуляркой

Tags: php

Есть категории товаров, которые отдаются в виде

```
{"СписокЗначений",{{{"Строка","КамАЗ"},"","0"},{{"Строка","BPW"},"","0"}}}
```

нужно из этого мусора вытащить только значения `КамАЗ` и `BPW`, и записать их через запятую, вот так: `КамАЗ,BPW`, как это можно сделать?

P.S. категорий может быть и одна и две и три и больше.

Comment: откуда они в таком виде кривом отдаются то? Слово `Строка` всегда присутствует и только в этом месте? и проверьте корректность указания числа скобок фигурных, а тов одном месте 3, в другом две

Comment: та какой-то древний xml экспорт товаров, мне его нужно правильно прочесть для импорта, `Строка` да, только в этих местах есть.

Comment: со скобками вроде все сходится `"СписокЗначений",{` и открывается скобка, дальше сами значения `{{"Строка","КамАЗ"},"","0"},{{"Строка","BPW"},"","0"}` потом закрывается скобка

Comment: Может это какой-то особый формат и его можно как-то прочесть....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поле чудес спешит на помощь!

```
$str = '{"СписокЗначений",{{{"Строка","КамАЗ"},"","0"},{{"Строка","BPW"},"","0"}}}';
preg_match_all('/\{"Строка","(?<aaaaaavtomobiiiil>[^"]+)"\}/', $str, $matches);
echo implode(",", $matches['aaaaaavtomobiiiil']);
// КамАЗ,BPW
```

Главное - ключевое слово "Аааавтомобиииль"!

Comment: Ахах, ключевое слово - зачет)) Огромное спасибо)

Answer (score 1):

Просто ради варианта

```
$text = '{"СписокЗначений",{{{"Строка","КамАЗ"},"","0"},{{"Строка","BPW"},"","0"}}}';
$text = str_replace(['{','}'], ['[',']'], $text);
$array = eval("return $text;");

$cars = [];
foreach($array[1] as $value){
    $cars[] = $value[0][1];
}

echo implode(",", $cars);
```